# Attacking with no mouse?

Tags: civilization-5, keyboard

Per in-game tooltips, I can see that one may press `A` or `B` to open the Attack or Ranged Attack menus, respectively (as well as to do *nearly* everything in-game without the mouse).

However, is it possible to **actually attack** without the mouse? Can I use *only* my keyboard to attack? I have a bit of repetitive strain injury on my right hand, so I'd like to go full-keyboard if at all possible.

Solutions not involving 3rd-party software *highly* preferred.

Comment: I can't say for certain but I think you can hit enter or some other affirmative key to trigger the attack - as for swapping targets, I'm not sure

Comment: Do you consider the Windows native accessibility features as "third-party software" or not?

Comment: @Mark Ehh, I don't currently have any PCs with Windows on them, so it wouldn't be useful _to me_, or answer the question _precisely_ as-stated (2K/Aspyr is the 1st party; I am the second party; PC/OS vendors would indeed be a 3rd party) — though it **might be useful to others as a non-canonical answer**.

Comment: What specifically are you have problems with? The num pad on your keyboard should be able to provide the directionality, and you already indicate that you've got the melee/ranged attack triggers working...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Nope, that doesn't work. I just tested: took an Archer who had a shot on an enemy city 2 squares NW of him, pressed `B` to open the Ranged Attack menu, pressed `7`, and the archer _walked towards the city_ rather than firing. All 3 squares were flat, so it wasn't an issue of a hill blocking the shot.